# Forward incoming email traffic

Tags: centos, email, iptables

I have two CentOS servers - one for email and one for web hosting.

One domain, which we do not control, has the MX record incorrectly pointing to the web host.

What iptables config is needed to forward incoming emails to the email server?

The email clients will correctly connect to the dedicated email server so IMAP connections should be fine.

For info, the email server currently has the following ports open:

```
IMAP – port 143 STARTTLS
SMTP – port 587 STARTTLS
```

Also - will the SSL certificate have problems?
I am unable to set up SPF record for the domain, I guess no solution for that?
Any other problems I might have? I can see sending emails may be a problem as they will not originate from the same server as the MX record?

Thanks

Comment: Seems silly to accommodate this, logically you would just ignore their connections and force the domain owner to correctly configure their dns. Your ssl will have problems if the domains don't match

Comment: I agree with you - we are in fact taking legal action (basically the old web master is not releasing the domain but has left the DNS setup as is) - but until everything is sorted we need to ensure emails work... - the other option is switch the underlying IP addresses and forward HTTP traffic instead - not sure which is simpler

Comment: The problem with this approach is your `mail server` restriction based on client IP address (e.g blacklisting/whitelisting) doesn't work anymore. The reason is your mail server only see a client with IP address from `web server`.